# mysql　実行されずに改行され続ける

Tags: mysql

昨日からｍｙｓｑｌの勉強を始めました。
最初の言語設定ってハマっていて、SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%’;したいにも関わらず実行されません。
他にも実行されない事が何度もあります。これは何が原因なのでしょうか？
[image]

Comment: 「実行されないことがある」：実行できるコマンドや実行できることもあるのでしょうか？、また、コマンドが間違っているわけでは無いので環境の問題かと思われますが、環境について一切触れられていないので解答がつきづらいかと思います。MySQLのバージョン、インストール先の環境、作業開始からのコマンドライン入力履歴(現状だと不具合の状態しか記載されていないので不具合が発生する前のコマンドなども一緒に記載すると良いかもしれません)、また行末を`\G`にしても一緒でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もし質問に書かれた通り `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%’;` と入力されているのなら、`char%` を囲む右側の記号が間違っています。左側はあっています。

そのため `’;` や改行も文字列の一部だと認識され、続きの入力を促され続けることになります。

英語における引用符は `‘xxx’` `“xxx”` と左右で形の異なる文字を使いますが、プログラミング等では `'xxx'` `"xxx"` と左右の区別のない文字を使うことが多いです。日本語配列のキーボードであれば、半角英数を入力できる状態で Shift+7 を押して入力されるのが、今回必要な記号です。

参考 [引用符 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%95%E7%94%A8%E7%AC%A6#.E7.9B.B4.E7.B7.9A.E5.BD.A2)

Answer (score 0):

mysql コマンドの「`'>`」プロンプトは「`'`」が入力された後、閉じの「`'`」の入力待ちの状態です。どこかで開く「`'`」と閉じる「`'`」の対応がずれたのでしょう。

その状態で「`'`」を入力するとプロンプトが「`->`」になり、「`\c`」でクエリを中断できます。